# What is the difference between a sinc3 and a sinc6 filter?

Tags: verilog

I have implemented a sinc3 filter in Verilog as follows. Now I am trying to implement a sinc6 filter using the same methodology.

I am thinking to just increase the number of accumulators and differentiators to 6.

Could someone please tell me the difference between sinc3 and sinc6 filters? How should I implement a sinc6 filter?

This is my code for a sinc3 filter in verilog:

```
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module sinc3
(input mclk1, /* used to clk filter */
input reset, /* used to reset filter */
input mdata1, /* input data to be filtered */

output reg [15:0] DATA, /* filtered output*/
output reg data_en,
input [15:0] dec_rate
);

/* Data is read on negative clk edge */
reg [36:0] ip_data1;
reg [36:0] acc1;
reg [36:0] acc2;
reg [36:0] acc3;
reg [36:0] acc3_d2;
reg [36:0] diff1;
reg [36:0] diff2;
reg [36:0] diff3;
reg [36:0] diff1_d;
reg [36:0] diff2_d;

reg [15:0] word_count;

reg word_clk;
reg enable;

/*Perform the Sinc action*/
always @ (mdata1)
if(mdata1==0)
    ip_data1 <= 37'd0;
    /* change 0 to a -1 for twos complement */
else
    ip_data1 <= 37'd1;

/*Accumulator (Integrator)
Perform the accumulation (IIR) at the speed of the modulator.
Z = one sample delay MCLKOUT = modulators conversion bit rate */

always @ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset)
    begin
    /* initialize acc registers on reset*/
        acc1 <= 37'd0;
        acc2 <= 37'd0;
        acc3 <= 37'd0;
    end
    else
    begin
    /*perform accumulation process */
        acc1 <= acc1 + ip_data1;
        acc2 <= acc2 + acc1;
        acc3 <= acc3 + acc2;
    end
end

/*decimation stage (MCLKOUT/WORD_CLK) */
always @ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset)
begin
    if (reset)
        word_count <= 16'd0;
    else
    begin
        if ( word_count == dec_rate - 1 )
            word_count <= 16'd0;
        else
            word_count <= word_count + 16'b1;
    end
end

always @ ( negedge mclk1, posedge reset )
begin
if ( reset )
    word_clk <= 1'b0;
else
begin
    if ( word_count == dec_rate/2 - 1 )
        word_clk <= 1'b1;
    else if ( word_count == dec_rate - 1 )
        word_clk <= 1'b0;
    end
end

/*Differentiator (including decimation stage)
Perform the differentiation stage (FIR) at a lower speed.
Z = one sample delay WORD_CLK = output word rate */

always @ (negedge word_clk, posedge reset)
begin
    if(reset)
    begin
        acc3_d2 <= 37'd0;
        diff1_d <= 37'd0;
        diff2_d <= 37'd0;
        diff1 <= 37'd0;
        diff2 <= 37'd0;
        diff3 <= 37'd0;
    end
    else
    begin
        diff1 <= acc3 - acc3_d2;
        diff2 <= diff1 - diff1_d;
        diff3 <= diff2 - diff2_d;
        acc3_d2 <= acc3;
        diff1_d <= diff1;
        diff2_d <= diff2;
    end
end

/* Clock the Sinc output into an output register
WORD_CLK = output word rate */

always @ (negedge word_clk )
begin
    case ( dec_rate )
        16'd32:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[15:0] == 16'h8000) ? 16'hFFFF : {diff3[14:0], 1'b0};
        end
        16'd64:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[18:2] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[17:2];
        end
        16'd128:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[21:5] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[20:5];
        end
        16'd256:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[24:8] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[23:8];
        end
        16'd512:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[27:11] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[26:11];
        end
        16'd1024:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[30:14] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[29:14];
        end
        16'd2048:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[33:17] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[32:17];
        end
        16'd4096:begin
        DATA <= (diff3[36:20] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[35:20];
        end
        default:begin
            DATA <= (diff3[24:8] == 17'h10000) ? 16'hFFFF : diff3[23:8];
        end
    endcase
end

/* Synchronize Data Output*/
always@ (negedge mclk1, posedge reset )
begin
    if ( reset )
    begin
        data_en <= 1'b0;
        enable <= 1'b1;
    end
    else
    begin
        if ( (word_count == dec_rate/2 - 1) && enable )
        begin
            data_en <= 1'b1;
            enable <= 1'b0;
        end
        else if ( (word_count == dec_rate - 1)  && ~enable )
        begin
            data_en <= 1'b0;
            enable <= 1'b1;
        end
        else
            data_en <= 1'b0;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 2):

Three sinc filters in series  is a third-order sinc = \$sinc^3\$) and
... six sinc filters in series = \$sinc^6\$ or two \$sinc^3\$ filters in series.

### More info  ( *re*-search)

https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Sinc_filter   **Definition of SINC in t or f domains**
https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sbaa230/sbaa230.pdf  **Digital Filter Types in Delta-Sigma ADC**
https://www.mouser.cn/datasheet/2/609/ad7134-1857833.pdf  **alias free SD-ADC that uses** \$sinc^3 , sinc^6\$

Comment: @user237252 I'd suggest using a window, because repeated convolution leads towards a gaussian, and a single filter with a gaussian window will be much cheaper than 6 extra multiply-add for the convolutions. Unless your application requires it, of course.